# Inequality in a random triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-inequality

I'm studying the gravitationnal field produced by the Sun at a point at the surface of the Earth and at the center of the planet. I've reduced the situation to a geometry problem but I'm stucked with it. I've made a Geogebra simulation and I've seen that it works but I can't proove it correctly. I'm pretty sure it's easy to solve but I can't despite many tries...

Let ABC be a triangle. AC is the longest side. How can we simply prove that $AC^{\,2}\geq(AB-BC)^{\,2}$ ?

Any tips would be very very appreciated because I'm quite desperate with that ^_^'

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: hint: sum of two  sides is greater than third side

Comment: Try a few sets of numbers and that might help you see why the statement is true. Then you can work on the proof. Also look at what happens if you take the square root of both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the triangle inequality. If $AB,BC$ and $AC$ are the three sides of a triangle, then $AB+BC\ge AC$. The inequality is then manipulated as follows:

$$AB+BC-BC \ge AC-BC \Longrightarrow AB \ge AC-BC$$

Of course, the longest side of your triangle is $AC$, which allows us to write:

$$AC \ge AB \ge AC-BC$$

Now suppose that $BC\le AB$. Clearly, $AB \ge AB-BC \ge 0.$ Inserting this into the above inequality yields:

$$AC \ge AB \ge AC-BC \ge AB-BC$$

Now, we actually want the terminal terms of the inequality; the middle ones don't matter, so we can ignore them. This gets us $$AC\ge AB-BC \Longrightarrow AC^2\ge (AB-BC)^2$$ as desired. QED.

Note that it could be the case that $BC\ge AB$ instead of the other way around. No worries, the proof works exactly the same, except you'd begin by subtracting $AB$ in the starting inequality instead of $BC$. Either way, you get the same result, all as a consequence of the triangle inequality.

Comment: THANK YOU so much !
I was nearly reaching the goal but I've forgotten that if a<b so f(a)<f(b) if f is strictly increasing... I feel so dumb

Comment: @Ben no worries, happy to help :) don't beat yourself too much; I know all too well how easy it is to lose sight of the trees for the forest!